# Datepicker shows behind auto completion box asp.net

Tags: asp.net, datepicker

As the image describes, it gets hidden by the box... I tried adding

```
style="position: relative; z-index: 100000;"
```

but no luck

[image]

Comment: Just set `autocomplete="off"` for the control and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `autocomplete="off"` for the specific control or for the whole form by providing in the Form tag `<form id="form1" runat="server" autocomplete="off">` and it'll solve your problem.